# How Save Temporally NSMutableArray count?

Tags: iphone, ipad, sdk, ios6

I am new IOS, i will like to know how save temporally NSMutableArray count sow i can compare with the new count?

i add badge icon on the app with the count and remove when i click to the new row, but when i refresh and add new row the add all the badge again.

This is the code:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:self.parseResults.count];

return self.parseResults.count;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


NSInteger badge = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber];


if (badge > 0) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:(badge - 1)];
}

}
```

Thank

Comment: int tempCount = [array count];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:nombre forKey:@"MaxCount"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]
```

// Above code is for saving...

and for retriving back this max count you can write below code where ever you want my friend

```
 NSInteger getMax1=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"MaxCount"];//This is for getting stored max count...
```

let me know it is working or not...

Happy Coding...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your design is not a good one. Never do that.
Apllication badge number is not for storing user data, it's for giving visual indication to user's.

You need to use a temporary variable instead.

```
int tempCount  = 0;


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

   tempCount = self.parseResults.count;

   return self.parseResults.count;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tempCount > 0)
    {
       tempCount -=1;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank, i change in temporary variable